# Очистка переписки с ботом

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram-bot, бот

Буду короток.
Есть бот напсанный на `Python 3` с библиотекой `telebot`.

Нужно, что бы при вводе команды `/cls` все, что было выше этой команды стерлось.
Как это реализовать?

Исходный код:

```
import telebot


token = '...'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands= ['start', 'help'])
def answer_commands(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'clear')
    photo= open('fytch.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'You call me\nMy goal all show you\nLook')

@bot.message_handler(commands= [cls])
def cls():
passs

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете удалить сообщение через `telebot` методом `delete_message`, зная его `chat_id` и `message_id`. При этом соблюдая правила, приведенные в цитате ниже.

У бота нет доступа к истории сообщений. Поэтому для удаления сообщений потребуется сохранять `message_id` на своей стороне.

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - A dice message in a private chat can only be deleted if it was sent more than 24 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in private chats, groups, and supergroups.
> - Bots can delete incoming messages in private chats.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.

Comment: you can help to correctly compose this part?